# Does javascript allocate memory on the stack in Google chrome? How can the javascript stack be profiled?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory, memory-management

I am writing a large application in Google chrome that does many complex thermodynamic calculations and appears to be pushing the limits of my computer. When running it uses ~600 MB of memory as reported by the windows task manager. When I open the chrome task manager, it reports that javascript is using ~400 MB of memory with ~180 MB considered live.

I would like to profile it and see if I can reduce memory usage so I have tried to use the Chrome inspect tools to take heap snapshots of the ~20 web workers and the main thread. The largest of these has a heap size of 7 MB and the average heap size is < 3 MB. By my math, it seems like there should be a total heap size of around 60 MB.

My guess is that the remaining reported memory is being allocated on the stack. Does chrome compile functions so they use stack memory? What is the best method to profile this and see where most of the memory is being used?

Additional information: the application in question is extremely light on graphics / DOM (so all the memory usage is either directly or indirectly from javascript). It communicates using a SharedWorker to another rendering process which handles the graphics. It also spawns around 20 WebWorkers to do various calculations. These are only spawned when the page loads but are passed new calculations every second (but only if they have finished their previous calculations).

Comment: not to be dismissive, but do those other numbers matter? if you rework your app and save RAM, then windows should reflect the improvement, and if it doesn't, then it is really saving anything?

Comment: Of course I want to rework the app. However, right now I don't know which parts are responsible for the high memory usage. Knowing which WebWorker for instance is responsible for the most memory usage would allow me to focus on what changes to make. I was hoping that the memory profiling in Chrome would help with this, but I can't account for 90% of the memory usage reported by the profiler.